# nignx rewrite with or without if

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos, plesk

I recently enabled nginx + php-fpm on our centos plesk server. Apache has been stopped and i'm looking for a way to disable it completely.

I run a wordpress site that should be getting quite a bit of traffic in the next few days (1000+ concurrent). Here is my question:

I have these two options as far as i can tell regarding wordpress permalinks with nginx

rewrite /$ /index.php break;
--or--
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break; }

The first one work, and really fast at that too, but it breaks index.htlm in subdirectories, robots.txt, xml sitemap etc (404)

The second one works exactly like a want it but i get a performance hit. It takes about a sec more to start loading the page.

Any of you fine lads have any ideas as I couldn't find anything?

Comment: Use `try_files` and caching.
Also, it's best to put all static assets into separate dir(s), and setup nginx not to try rewrite and serve php from that dir(s).

Answer (score 1):

You should give this a read http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls it answers your question in the "Check IF File Exists" section.

A much better way than using if is to use a location match and try_files

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but how would i go about adding a / location rule through plesk? It won't let me as there is one already in the conf file by default. Is there a way to over rule it? Or do i have to edit the conf manually and 'breal' the panel?

Comment: I've never tried to configure anything nginx through plesk so I don't know.  I'd suspect you could change the template that the conf file is generated from though.